# How to compare decimals knowing there is room for error

Tags: c#, unit-testing, decimal

I have two different ways to calculate a value. Once both methods run, I get the following:

```
decimal a = 145.2344;
decimal b = 145.2345;
```

I have a unit test:

```
  Assert.AreEqual(a,b);
```

I want to be able to account for a +/- .0001 difference. How can I add this rule?

Comment: Which unit testing framework/asseveration library are you using?

Answer (score 16):

In [NUnit's *constraint model*](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=constraintModel&r=2.4.8), you can do this:

```
Assert.That(Math.Abs(a-b), Is.LessThan(0.0001M));
```

Better yet, make it a function:

```
void AssertDiff(decimal a, decimal b, decimal diff = 0.0001) {
     Assert.That(Math.Abs(a-b), Is.LessThan(diff));
}
```

**EDIT :** In MS Unit Test Framework, do this:

```
void AssertDiff(decimal a, decimal b, decimal diff = 0.0001) {
     Assert.IsTrue(Math.Abs(a-b) < diff);
}
```

Comment: @MichaelBray This is NUnit's *constraint model* introduced in NUnit 2.4. You can read about it [here](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=constraintModel&r=2.4.8).

Comment: @MichaelBray Ah, I just noticed the OP's comment, thank you very much! I edited my answer.

Comment: Would be nice if a method like AssertDiff were built directly into the framework. It's annoying to have a test fail and see a vague failure message like "Something was false when it should have been true", as opposed to a specific message like "Something was 150.0 when it should have been 100.0".

Comment: Declare the default number as a decimal rather than a double - 
void AssertDiff(decimal a, decimal b, decimal diff = 0.0001M) {

Comment: I'm not sure when this functionality was added (maybe not at the time of the answer above), but this isn't the best way anymore. The `Is.EqualTo()` has a modifier for `Within`. See [the documentation](https://nunit.org/docs/2.5.3/equalConstraint.html) for everything accessible using `.Within()` So this could be written as `Assert.That(Math.Abs(a-b), Is.EqualTo(0).Within(0.0001M))` or `Assert.That(a, Is.EqualTo(b).Within(0.0001M))`

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Do we actually need `Abs` when we use `Within`? I.e. can we simply write `Assert.That(a, Is.EqualTo(b).Within(0.0001M))`?

Answer (score 4):

Simple:

```
if (Math.Abs(a-b) < 0.0001m)
    // equal
```